# Remove a specific table row on onClick event in React component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm new to React and struggling on how to manipulate the DOM after I have deleted a record. I have a few react components but the one I am focused on is to delete a record in a rails api I have set up. I have the record deleting ok on the Ajax onclick call, but don't know the best way to remove the specific row using React.

Table full of data

```
var ContactAll = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      contacts: [] 
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: '/all-contacts',
      type: "GET",
      context: this,
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        this.setState({ contacts: data });
      }
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    if(this.state.contacts == 0) {
      return (
        <div>Loading</div>
      )
    } else {
      var contactComponents = this.state.contacts.map(function(contact, i) {
        var full_name = contact.first_name + ' ' + contact.last_name

        return  <tr key={i} className="contact">
                  <td>{ full_name}</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>{ contact.email_address }</td>
                  <td>{ contact.phone_number }</td>
                  <td>{ contact.company_name }</td>
                  <td><DeleteButton email={contact.email_address} /></td>
                </tr>;
      });
      return <div>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Contact Name</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Email Address</th>
                  <th>Phone Number</th>
                  <th>Company Name</th>
                </tr>

                {contactComponents};

                </tbody>
              </table>
             </div>
    }
  }
});
```

Delete Button within ContactAll component

```
var DeleteButton = React.createClass({
  onClick: function() {
    var email = this.props.email;

    $.ajax({
      data: {email_address: email },
      url: '/delete-contact',
      dataType: 'html',
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        $('.delete-success').slideDown(400);
        setTimeout(function() { $(".delete-success").slideUp(400); }, 5000);
      }
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <button onClick={() => { this.onClick(this.props.email) }}>Delete</button>
    )
  }
});
```

What is the best way of removing the specific row that gets deleted when the delete button for the corresponding row is clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a delete function and then send the index of the array into that and use splice to remove that array entry. Pass reference to this deleteRow function to the child component and call it from there like `this.props.deleteRow(this.props.index);` .Check out the complete code

like

```
deleteRow: function(index) {
    var contacts = [...this.state.contacts];
    contacts.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({contacts});
  },
```

```js
var ContactAll = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      contacts: [] 
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: '/all-contacts',
      type: "GET",
      context: this,
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        this.setState({ contacts: data });
      }
    });
  },
  deleteRow: function(index) {
    var contacts = [...this.state.contacts];
    contacts.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({contacts});
  },
  render: function(){
    if(this.state.contacts == 0) {
      return (
        <div>Loading</div>
      )
    } else {
      var contactComponents = this.state.contacts.map(function(contact, i) {
        var full_name = contact.first_name + ' ' + contact.last_name

        return  <tr key={i} className="contact">
                  <td>{ full_name}</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>{ contact.email_address }</td>
                  <td>{ contact.phone_number }</td>
                  <td>{ contact.company_name }</td>
                  <td><DeleteButton onClick ={this.deleteRow.bind(this)} index={i} email={contact.email_address} /></td>
                </tr>;
      }.bind(this));
      return <div>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Contact Name</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Email Address</th>
                  <th>Phone Number</th>
                  <th>Company Name</th>
                </tr>

                {contactComponents};

                </tbody>
              </table>
             </div>
    }
  }
}); 
var DeleteButton = React.createClass({
  onClick: function() {
    var email = this.props.email;
    this.props.deleteRow(this.props.index);
    $.ajax({
      data: {email_address: email },
      url: '/delete-contact',
      dataType: 'html',
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        $('.delete-success').slideDown(400);
        setTimeout(function() { $(".delete-success").slideUp(400); }, 5000);
      }
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <button onClick={() => { this.onClick(this.props.email) }}>Delete</button>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you check the solution. Let me know if you have any routes

Comment: Hi Shubham, thanks for this. I am getting an error in the DeleteButton component, 'this.props.deleteRow' is not a function. What could be the problem?

Comment: @luke it seems that the binding was not proper so deleteRow couldn't be passed as a function to the child. Try using bind(this) in the map component in parent. I edited the code for it

Comment: I managed to figure it out. i ended up using that = this trick. `deleteRow={ that.deleteRow.bind(that) }`

Comment: Yep, right  that also a way apart from what I suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

to remove or update an elemento i would recommend refresh the page, like this simple code:

```
const handleDelete = async () => {
    try {
      await updateElement(currentDesign.uid, { is_public: !is_public })
      fetchAllDataToTable({})
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMessage(
        'An error occurred while attempting to delete or update, please try again later'
      )
    }
  }
```

fetchAllDataToTable is where you get all of the data for your table

```
const fetchAllDataToTable = async ({}) => {

    try {
      let { designs } = await fetchData(
        null,
        limit,
        lastElement, 
      )

      setList(designs)
```